# Typescript/ESLint : override getter and call the super method (error ts(2340) and ts(2339))

Tags: typescript, eslint, getter-setter, super

With Typescript, I create classes with getter. I want to redefine some getter but using the super. Now when I enter the following lines of code, I have these error messages:

```
class A  {
   protected get style(): React.CSSProperties | undefined {
      return {width: '100%'};
   }
}

class B extends B {
   protected get style(): React.CSSProperties | undefined {
      return super.style;
   }
}
```

> Only public and protected methods of the base class are accessible via the 'super' keyword.ts(2340)

If I type :

```
this.super.style
```

, the editor (VSCode) tells me that super does not exist on this

> Property 'super' does not exist on type 'A'.ts(2339)

Answer (score 1):

This [seems to work fine](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=11&ssc=7&pln=11&pc=13#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4BYAKCrQBsUBnBuAQTjgG8r24wcYkGJABM4AcyTwGMAJ60kACgCUALkTEYAOgDCAZV0AFHGCSxgSZgB84AVwB2wpJmB2Rnbj3ZEYNqHc4A7sDCMAAWagDkAIwADDEApBEAvhSUPElUGdSUdIzMAEJwSAAeAg7MbFxp7HwQAkKiElKy8spqyOhaeobGpjDmVrYOTi5uVZ5ekr7%20DDYmUJrSckip6ZlAA):

```
class B extends A {
   protected get style(): React.CSSProperties | undefined {
      return super.style;
   }
}
```

Of course in your example there is no point to extending the `style` getter since it returns the same value that it would otherwise.

Comment: I agree with you. To date, my getter on my child class is useless in my example, but the goal is to overload. on my side, when I call super.style, I always have the error in VSCode : Only public and protected methods of the base class are accessible via the 'super' keyword. ts (2340)

Comment: If I transform my getter into a getStyle method I have no error ...

Comment: That might be the way to go.  To be honest I was a bit surprised that the typescript playground allowed accessing a property from `super`.